# declareUpdate causing delay

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

To clean up my database, I run a script that deletes some documents. This script needs the `declareUpdate()` statement to be able to delete documents. But this causes extreme calculation times.
For example: the following never finishes with `declareUpdate()` in the script.

```
cts.remainder(fn.subsequence(fn.collection("deleteThis"), 1, 1))
```

This runs in a second without the `declareUpdate()`. Is it maybe checking all the reader/writer permissions on all the documents in `cts.remainder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, fn.collection reaches all docs in that collection, and in update mode uri read locks are applied for all of them. You are better off using cts.uris with a collection query, and then batch delete the docs in spawns..

HTH!